# How to compare enumerations of elements in list?

Tags: c#, enums

I have to implement a poker game using Test-Driven Development. Now I have to check if the given hand contains straight flush. So I have to check the enumerations of each card if is greater with one than the previous one. Let me show some code.

```
public bool IsStraightFlush(IHand hand)
    {
        var sortedCards = hand.Cards.OrderBy(card => card.Face).ThenBy(card => card.Suit);

    }
```

Each card is declaring by two parameters of enums: `public Card(CardFace face, CardSuit suit)`
CardFace and CardSuits are enums.
Here's what I wrote for now - I sorted the given hand as parameter consisted of five cards. I ordered first by face, then by suit. Now I have to know how to check if the next card of the hand has the CardFace enum + 1 than the current one. Here's the enumeration for CardFace.

```
 public enum CardFace
{
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4,
    Five = 5,
    Six = 6,
    Seven = 7,
    Eight = 8,
    Nine = 9,
    Ten = 10,
    Jack = 11,
    Queen = 12,
    King = 13,
    Ace = 14
}
```

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, you want to compare two Ienumarable list of same type. You can use Enumerable.SequenceEqual method to compare. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx

Comment: No, I want to compare the CardFace enum of each card in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work :

```
public bool IsStraightFlush(IHand hand)
    {
        var sortedCards = hand.Cards.OrderBy(card => card.Face).ThenBy(card => card.Suit).ToList();
        bool straightFlush = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < sortedCards.Count(); i++)
        {
            if ((int)sortedCards[i].Face != (int)sortedCards[i - 1].Face + 1)
            {
                straightFlush = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return straightFlush;
    }
```

Comment: Okey, perfectly pass all the tests I wrote before. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, cast you sequence to int, then check that `next element -1` equals current:

```
    static bool CheckForSequence(List<int> input)
    {
        input.Sort();
        var result = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            result = input[i] == input[i + 1] - 1;
            if (!result)
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And one more solution, you still need to cast ti `int`, but it much shorter:

```
    static bool CheckForSequence(List<int> input)
    {
        return !input.OrderBy(p => p).Select((p, i) => p - i).Distinct().Skip(1).Any();
    }
```

In this case, if collection sequential, difference between item and index will be same for all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `group by` and then checking that there is a single group and all the cars within it are sequential.

```
public bool IsStraightFlush(IHand hand)
{
   var sortedCards = from c in hand.Cards
                     group c by c.Suit into d             
                     select new
                     {
                        Suit = d.Key,
                        Cards = d.OrderBy(x => x.Face)
                     };

    // all cards are the same suit              
    if(sortedCards.Count() == 1)
    {
        Card previousCard = null;
        foreach (var card in sortedCards.First().Cards)
        {
            if(previousCard != null && (card.Face - previousCard.Face > 1))
            {
                return false;
            }

            previousCard = card;
        }

        return true;
    }

   return false;
}

void Main()
{
    var hand = new Hand 
    {
        Cards = new List<Card>
        {
            new Card { Face = CardFace.Two, Suit = CardSuit.Clubs },
            new Card { Face = CardFace.Three, Suit = CardSuit.Clubs },
            new Card { Face = CardFace.Four, Suit = CardSuit.Clubs },
            new Card { Face = CardFace.Five, Suit = CardSuit.Clubs },
            new Card { Face = CardFace.Six, Suit = CardSuit.Clubs },
        }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(IsStraightFlush(hand));

}
```